# Many drawbacks and problems when i enable the "Community Site Feature" inside my team sites

Tags: 2013, team-sites, newsfeed, architecture, community-site

this week i have faced many problems when i enable the "Community Site Feature" on my team sites inside my on-premises 2013 farm.
now we have the following structure:-

1. 2 site collections of type Team Site.
2. inside those site collections we have many sub-sites of type team site (30++ sub-sites in total) and each sub-site represent a unique Project or Programe and have unique permission.
3. also inside the 30++ team sub-sites, each sub-site have a Discussion Bard list.
4. now our customer have been working on these sites for around 1 year without any major problem.
5. now our customer asked us that they want to be able to mention users inside the Discussion lists. and based on my reading this can not be accomplished unless we enable the "Community Site Feature". so inside some test sub-sites i enable this feature.

but i got many drawbacks/side-effects, which are:-

1. the team sub-site will no longer have the option to be saved as template.
2. also the team site will have 3 new unnecessary lists + 3 unnecessary new groups.
3. also the built-in Pages list will start having a unique permission inside it.
4. also on some sub-sites mentioning users will be shown as an activity inside the users my-site while on other it will not (i have asked another question about this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226216/mention-someone-inside-a-discussion-board-will-be-shown-inside-the-mysitenews) )

so all-in-all seems that enabling this feature inside the team sites will be a headache. so i am not sure how i need to appraoch this from business/technical perspectives. now i am planning to inform the customer the following:-

1. will mention to them the drawbacks of enabling this feature inside the team site. and that Team Sites by nature are not community sites.
2. if they want to Tag/@Mention users inside the team site they still can do so inside the team sites' NewsFeed area which will work out of the box inside the team sites without having to enable anything. and will always appear as an activity inside the users' my-site
3. also we can create a unique community site collection to create discussion and mention users.. but not inside the team sites.

so can anyone adivce if my above 3 points which i am planning to communicate with our customer are considered valid/reasonable?